# Is it possible to define functions in order to avoid spaghetti code?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Recently I started learning `tikz`, and my codes have longer and longer, mostly because I had to copy and paste a lot of code. Now in many programming languages you could define functions/methods, but can you do that in `tikz` too?

Comment: First, latex is not so much a programming language as a (very powerful) macro expansion language, so it does not have functions or methods *per se*.This said, the pgfkeys interface to tikz is incredibly powerful and can be used to write code that effectively does what you want. The style and code handlers in tikz are obvious examples. As another, have a look at the "pic syntax" section of the tikz/pgf manual (this is section 18.2 on page 251 in version 3.0.1a of the manual). As you have not given explicit examples of the sort of code you want to rationalise it is difficult to say more.

Comment: Also take a look at the tikz (actually pgf) `\foreach` syntax in the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\newcommand` to define specific parts of your drawing.

Example:

```
\newcommand{\valve}[2]{%
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-1,-0.5)}]
        \draw[fill=white] (0+#1,0+#2) -- (2+#1,1+#2) -- (2+#1,0+#2) 
                                      -- (0+#1,1+#2) -- (0+#1,0+#2);
    \end{scope}
}
```

Usage:

```
\valve{2}{16};
```

Comment: Oh great, that is probably the closest you can get, thank you very much!